# Is there a quick way to convert a byte array to a string?

Tags: java, string, byte

In Java, it takes too much time to convert a very large byte array to a string. Is there another good way ??

```
byte [] buf = new byte[100000];
new String(buf).trim();
```

Comment: Check to see what it does internally and try to distribute it amongst multiple threads with logical byte[] boundaries and get it done parallel

Comment: The fastest way is to avoid doing it. Which means you need data processing working on the bytes. In some cases this is easy, in others not. There is no way around the String creation (it might get faster with compact strings for Latin1 charset in Java 9 (JEP254))

Comment: perhaps avoid the trim(), which can result in a new String which might create a new internal char array. if you know the length of the data in the buf, or can search it for the null terminator, use: new String(buf, 0, calculatedLength) and dont add .trim()

Comment: @slippery don't forget that the string might start with whitespace, so you'd need to calculate an index instead of zero to start at.

Comment: @eckes of course, the string construction is entirely unnecessary, as it is created and discarded immediately. So not doing it at all is the best thing to do.

Comment: @AndyTurner that's true. i assumed the trim was because of trailing zeros in the byte array, not white space itself. but yes, if there is white space it could be pre-searched for.

Comment: pamiers can you actually confirm the trim() is needed and the actual return value is assigned to a variable and used. Otherwise @AndyTurner is of course right and you can just remove the statement :)

Comment: Provide a complete testable code. Especially showing how you measure "long time", then we can test and improve the code. My method uses `For` loop so I don't know if that's faster than what you got.

Answer (score -1):

You could use:
    new String(bytes, charset);

Edit: if you want to write this into a file, use Files.write bytes, else, then you probably should try to use a for loop, and use multiple threads. I am not too experienced with java, but I don't think their is a faster way than iterating through the array because you need all the elements.

Comment: And that's faster?

Comment: I've tried it before, but it has no effect.
I noticed slower performance in creating strings if the length of the bytes was longer. Is there a better way?

Comment: Well, I think at the very least you need a for loop through all the items in the array, but I guess you could make 4 threads, or however many CPUs your computer have, and have them each do 1/4 of the work, and then add them all to a string.

Comment: This will be no faster than what OP is doing already (aside from the trim) as this is what OP is doing already (just with the default charset).

Comment: You can't generate one string instance in multiple threads but you could do it for partial strings.

Comment: No, but create a string instance and than add to it with multiple threads.